# Apply multiple FontStyles to Richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i need some help to figure out how to set bold,italic,underline to the same text into a richtextbox..
So far i have been doing this...

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim texto As String

    Public Sub seleccionCB()

        If CBNegrita.Checked = True Then
            txtTexto.Font = New Font(txtTexto.Font, FontStyle.Bold)

        Else
            txtTexto.Font = New Font(txtTexto.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
            If CBCursiva.Checked = True Then
                txtTexto.Font = New Font(txtTexto.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
            Else
                txtTexto.Font = New Font(txtTexto.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
                If CBSub.Checked = True Then
                    txtTexto.Font = New Font(txtTexto.Font, FontStyle.Underline)
                Else
                    txtTexto.Font = New Font(txtTexto.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
                End If

            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: your IFs are nested so you are only going to end up with one setting instead of combining Bold with Italic or whatever.  Compare your question of "how to set bold AND italic AND..." with the code which is set to assume is it bold OR italic OR...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine multiple values using the bitwise `Or` operator, for instance:

```
txtTexto.Font = New Font(txtTexto.Font, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)
```

However, in your case, where you need to check each one with a condition, you can do it like this:

```
Dim style As FontStyle = FontStyle.Regular
If CBNegrita.Checked Then style = style Or FontStyle.Bold
If CBCursiva.Checked Then style = style Or FontStyle.Italic
If CBSub.Checked Then style = style Or FontStyle.Underline
txtTexto.Font = New Font(txtTexto.Font, style)
```

Comment: thanks fellow.. its works like a charm...! I had days google on